# Grow HFS+ partition at the end of harddrive without partition-manager-cd or moving to another drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I've got two HFS+ partitions and would like to grow the latter one but neither disk utility nor the commandline `diskutil` allow that.

I **don't** want copy the whole partition to another drive and then copy it back.
I also **don't** want to use some kind of Boot-CD because I'm really lazy.

So are there any other options.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php)

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend iPartition. It will allow you to resize partitions without deleting any data. It also works for Boot Camp volumes and other PC disks.

> With iPartition, resizing a partition is as simple as selecting it, grabbing the resize handle and dragging. Not only that, but if you have several operations to perform, iPartition lets you queue them up and run them one after another, so you can have a cup of coffee while iPartition works. This feature, coupled with iPartition’s ability to automatically rearrange your existing partitions when necessary, makes iPartition the easiest partitioning tool that you’ll ever use.
>
> [image]

Comment: doesn't work on the System-drive without creating a Boot-CD. Therefore I don't consider this a viable alternative.

Comment: @Hedge Since you has the second drive selected in Disk Utility, I thought that was a secondary drive. **Modifying the startup partition whilst booted into said partition is impossible.** You need to boot into something else, whether that be a Live CD or other bootable disk.

Comment: Sorry, the first HDD is a SSD which gets ejected after 5 minutes of use so don't bother with it! I will try to run iPartition when booted in another OS X.